# How to add redirect link in json object in dynamo db

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

How to add redirect link to particular text in JSON object. For example,

- My json attribute name is "**submissionFailed**" and the value is "**Submission Failed. Please Contact Company for more information**"
- Here I need to add redirect link "**www.google.com**" only to the "**Contact Company**" in the value.

Please check my sample JSON :

```js
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New"},
      {"value": "Open"},
      {"value": "Close"}
    ]
  },
  "submissonFailed" : "Submission Failed. Please Contact Company for more information"
}}
```

How to add link like in json file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you add to DynamoDB, this is something you need to do while rendering the data on your client. For example of it's a html webpage using handlebars it would look like:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New"},
      {"value": "Open"},
      {"value": "Close"}
    ]
  },
  "submissonFailed" : "Submission Failed.",
   "url": "https:google.com",
   "company": "contact company"
}}
```

.

```
<p>{{ item.submissionFailed }} <a href={{ item.url }}> {{ item.company }}</a>.</p>
```